# Multiple single-node clusters on one machine

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing

Hadoop provides mini-cluster CLI for testing purposes. However in situations where I need 2 clusters for testing purposes, is it possible to run multiple instances of this mini-cluster on one machine? Or do I need to use VM or another machines?

Answer (score 0):

According to Hadoop

> Using the CLI MiniCluster, users can simply start and stop a single-node Hadoop cluster with a single command, and without the need to set any environment variables or manage configuration files. The CLI MiniCluster starts both a YARN/MapReduce & HDFS clusters.

Since MiniCluster use default port for Datanode, Namenode and so on, it is recommended to use another machine or run on different virtual machines. However, if you change the bin directory and all default ports for the second mini-cluster, you can run multi mini-cluster in one machine which is very confusing and not recommended.